# Comparing dates in google Spreadsheet

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets, compare, gs-conditional-formatting

I want to compare two dates in Column D and E. Column D is Due Date a column E is Completion date. I want to compare the two dates and see if the Due Date is less than or equal to the Completion date then both cells turn green otherwise turn red if their overdue.

I'm not good at programming but this is what I have so far:

```
function myFunction() {

function onEdit(e) {

var cellID = e.source.getActiveCell();
//var cellValue = e.cell.getValue();     
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; //”0? is the first sheet
var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process-actual row# (this is cell D2)
var numRows = 206 // Number of rows to process (goes from D2-D206)
var data = dataRange.getValues();
for (i in data) {
var row = data[i];

  if (row[4] > row[3] ) {
    cellID.setBackgroundColor('red');
  } else if(row[4] <= row[3]) {
    cellID.setBackgroundColor('green');
  }  
}  
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to do what you want with the built-in conditional formatting now in the new Sheets. Have you tried?

On the script, onEdit() was thrown inside myFunction(), which isn't going to work. Comment if you want to go further with the script.

Answer (score 0):

Clear any conditional formatting from ColumnsD:E, select ColumnsD:E fill with (standard) green and Format, Conditional formatting..., Format cells if... `Custom formula is` and

```
=and(row()<>1,$E1<$D1)
```

with red fill and <kbd>Done</kbd>.